# Excel- Find matching values then compare additional respective values

Tags: excel, formulas

I have been struggling with creating a complex formula to accomplish the following:

I am using 2 sheets of data within a workbook. I want to first find exact account number matches between the two sheets. (ie. On sheet two there are specific accounts I want to find in sheet 1- which holds all account numbers) I think I accomplished this with formula =COUNTIF('Sheet 2"!$A:$A,F1)>0  [account numbers are in column "f" in sheet 1] - they are all currently highlighted in sheet 1.

I now want to take those matches and compare the respective values listed in each separate sheet. (ie. I have now found all the accounts I need in sheet 1. Lets say account ABC is one account of interest. ABC's value is in column B of sheet 2. I want to compare the value I have listed in column C of sheet 1 to see if it is < or =.

I am not that advanced in excel formulas; you all are way smarter than I, so hoping you can help!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please properly format your question and explicitly show input and expected output. This helps in understanding and answering your question.

Comment: I'd start by learning how to use the vlookup formula - I'm pretty sure this is what you need. It's very easy to use once you have learned it.

Comment: Apologies, the spacing disappeared when I entered the question. I do know how to use the vlookup formula. I am pretty sure this will not solve the issue, or at least the complete issue. I could definitely be mistaken, so if you provide some explanation I could verify.